# How do I access a static IP based Unix server from my home internet?

Tags: linux, networking, windows, putty

I have a UNIX static IP based server running RHEL 5.11 and want to access it via Putty/Command Line and via WinSCP over the internet from my home computer. As my home internet doesn't has a static IP address how do I configure the specified access for the same on my home computer

Thanks in advance!
**EDIT**
I have a windows based home machine with dynamic IP internet access through which i want to access my the static IP based UNIX server that's it.

Comment: there is no need of configuration for outgoing traffic (home computer to server). Is the server you want to reach behind a firewall/NAT whaever ?

Comment: I have a windows based home machine with dynamic IP internet access through which i want to access my the static IP based UNIX server that's it.

Answer (score 1):

To access a static IP based computer , your computer no need to have static IP.

1. To access your static IP server from your home you need to have SSH service installed in your static IP server.
   As you said it's a RHEL server and if yum configured then do as

   ```
   sudo yum install openssh-server openssh-clients
   ```

Get the IP of your server with ifconfig command.

To check service running or not give

```
service sshd status

service sshd start
```

And

stop,   restart.

.

2. Install putty or any other SSH tools in your home machine and give IP of that machine.
3. Note : make sure you adding firewall rule in iptables for adding ssh port to access your RHEL server.

Edit : Hey OP , to access your home machine which is not having a static IP you can put it in a VPN and next time you can connect to it by connecting to the same VPN.

Else you can use some remote access tools like team viewer to access your home computer and type of your IP connectivity doesn't matter.

Note : hope you know team viewer is a GUI tool.

Comment: He is not running Linux locally, so your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @ThomasDickey why should this answer need running Linux locally? Maybe you misread?

Comment: OP is asking how to configure his home computer, which is a Windows machine.  Perhaps you are answering a question which was not yet asked.

Comment: Hello Mr Thomas Dicky. I updated my answer with reasonable content which could help OP a bit. Thank you for pointing my mistake